# Edit single page from plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, single

Hello guys I am creating a plugin in which I am making a custom post type season.
Now I would like to echo something on season single page based on a database query.
I have query and logics figured out but I want to echo on season single page from plugin file only not creating a single template and then use filter like post type template.
If you could only show echo 'hello world'; on only post_type="season" that would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the `the_content` filter:

```
/**
 * Adds some text to bottom of the content on 'season' pages.
 *
 * @param   string  $content    The current content of the season page.
 * @return  string              The new content of the season page.
 */
function add_season_content( $content ) {

    if ( is_singular( 'season' ) && is_main_query() ) {

        // collect your season data over here...
        $season_data = 'Hello world';

        $content .= $season_data;
    }

    return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_season_content' );
```

Place this code anywhere inside your plugin files.

Comment: Thanks Jhu I figured it would be the_content filter but my code was not working.
Yours worked like a charm.
Thank you for taking time and answering

Comment: Cool! Would you mind marking it as the right answer?